# Facebook Fresco progressive JPEG

Tags: android, http, decode, fresco

try to avoid the loss of image data during a running download from my server via a Fresco ImageRequest.

Everything runs perfect, but if the connection fails (interruption of network connectivity), the image is gone. But as I know, some Scans has been decoded (LogCat -> Intermediate image received!). But how to access them? Is there a way to save every single Scan in a seperate file? To access the latest version, if the phone goes offline?

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fresco doesn't fully support this functionality. Please [file an issue](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/new) on GitHub.